# MS Access 2010 Can't add Attachment to Attachment Field type if currently zero attachments

Tags: ms-access, attachment

I'm using MS Access 2010 and have some SQL and VBA but primarily let Access do the background programming.

I currently have an issue regarding an inability to add an Attachment to an "Attachment" field type if that field is currently empty.  It works fine if there are already existing attachments for that field in a given record.

In Form with Format "Datasheet", the records with zero attachments in the Attachment field type display as "#ERROR".  The ones that do have attachments (say 1), the 1 displays but with no paperclip and can't click to view.

In Single Form View (only one record displayed), the empty field appears with paperclip and "0".  Hovering over the field yields "Double-click to view or add attachments" but the double-click is non-functioning. (yes I've tried speeding up and slowing down pace of double-clicks.)  If there are indeed current attachments, double-click works normally... appreciate any insight you could provide

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Can you add the attachment directly in table? Cannot replicate issue. Would have to examine db to analyze.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I neglected to mention that the attachment is in a joined table.  There is no error code.  The only code I have to share is that generated by Access.

Comment: Yes I can add directly to the table.  The attachment is inert on the query upon which the form is attached.  I hope this link works and helps to show you what I'm seeing in the query.                 https://drive.google.com/open? id=1aBUXPg5MvyT4rYCtQEfWjzarq6wdQ18U

Comment: meant to say "... the query which provides the data for the form.."